# Checking one checkbox is checking all other checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, redux, checkbox, redux-toolkit

I have a checkbox component whose state is handled in Redux Toolkit. When checking one checkbox it's checking all other checkboxes in all rows, but I only want to check the checkbox I click on.
Here's my code below:

Checkbox Component:

```
export const Checkbox = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const handleCheckBox = () => {
        dispatch(checkboxState)
    }


    const isChecked = useSelector((state) => (
        state.isChecked
    ))


    return (
        <input type='checkbox' checked={isChecked} onChange={handleCheckBox}/>
    )
}
```

Slice:

```
const rowState = {
    data: [],
    isChecked: false,
    loading: false
}


export const rowSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'rows',
    initialState: rowState,
    reducers: {
        CHECK_ROWS(state) {
            state.isChecked = !state.isChecked
        },
})

export const checkboxState = rowSlice.actions.CHECK_ROWS()
```

Then I'm calling the checkbox component in my page:

```
    const handleRows = (rowData) => {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <Checkbox />
                </td>
//rest of the code
            </tr>

   return(
            <Table>
                {
                    dataSource.map((data) => (
                        handleRows(data)
                    ))
                }
            </Table>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are keeping one variable `isChecked` for the entire component. To make it unique to each data, keep this as an array:

```
const rowState = {
    data: [],
    checkedData: [],
    loading: false
}
```

Then, you should update the `checkedData` array accordingly. Check state will receive an id or an index and remove from `checkedData` if it is present in `checkecData` or add to `checkedData` if it is not present.

*An example:*

```
checkedData.includes(index) ? checkedData.filter((d,i) => i !== index) : [...checkedData, index]
```

Comment: Thank you, but what should I do in the slice instead of what I did?  or how do I do this in the slice? I'm new to redux so I would appreciate some help in this too

Comment: Actually, I have never used `redux-toolkit`. The logic is as what I said, remove if exists, add if not. But can't help about the implementation unfortunately.

Comment: but regarding the example, that's how you meant I should update my state, right? I can pass this to actions if so

Comment: Yeah you should pass the index to the action that will update the state, and you can update the array like I provided in the example

Answer (score 0):

Each checkbox should need an index, and the state should keep track of which checkbox that is checked or not.

```js
import { useSelector, Provider, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { createAction, createReducer, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = { checkboxes: [false, false, false] };

const index = createAction("toggle/index");
const toggleReducer = createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  builder.addCase(index, (state, action) => {
    state.checkboxes[action.payload] = !state.checkboxes[action.payload];
  });
});

const store = configureStore({ reducer: toggleReducer });

const toggleIndex = (index) => {
  return {
    type: "toggle/index",
    payload: index,
  };
};

export const Checkbox = ({ index }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleCheckBox = () => {
    dispatch(toggleIndex(index));
  };

  const isChecked = useSelector(({ checkboxes }) => checkboxes[index]);

  return (
    <input type="checkbox" checked={isChecked} onChange={handleCheckBox} />
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div>
        <Checkbox index={0} />
        <Checkbox index={1} />
        <Checkbox index={2} />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```